# Getting "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'document'" this error in python I'm working with Word2Vec and gensim

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm working on project using Word2vec and gensim,

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(
    documents = 'userDataFile.txt',
    size=150,
    window=10,
    min_count=2,
    workers=10)
model = gensim.model.Word2Vec.load("word2vec.model")
model.train(documents, total_examples=len(documents), epochs=10)
model.save("word2vec.model")
```

this is the part code that I have at the moment, and I'm getting this error below

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\InstaSubProject\templates\HashtagData.py", line
>
> 37, in <module>
> workers=10)
> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'documents'
> ```

`UserDataFile.txt` is the file that I stored output result data that I got from web scraping.

I'm not really sure what I need to fix here.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Isn't it `sentences` argument instead of `documents`?

Answer (score 94):

The year is 2021 and if you're here for the same reason I am, it's because you're getting the same error on the `size` parameter.

You need to use `vector_size` instead.

Comment: I could swear that 3 days ago I was running a word2vec model with size, and today I've had to upvote your comment for how spot on it was.

edit: could it be because 3 days ago I was running said model on Python 3.8 and now I'm doing it on a VM that has Python 3.6?

Comment: i am having the same issue with param `iter`

Comment: @SunilGarg I don't think there is an `iter` parameter for Word2vec. There is `epochs` but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: @SunilGarg I've experienced the same issue with `iter`. Heres what the documentation says:
```epochs (int, optional) – Number of iterations (epochs) over the corpus. (Formerly: iter)```

Comment: Released Mar. 31 2021 3.x -> 4
https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4

Answer (score 5):

Use **vector_size** instead of size

```
# creating a word to vector model
model_w2v = gensim.models.Word2Vec(
            tokenize_data,
            vector_size=200)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try see this new update from v3 to v4:
[link](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4)

```
model = Word2Vec(size=100, …)  # 
model = Word2Vec(vector_size=100, …)  #
```

Answer (score 1):

`__init__()` is the class constructor for Word2Vec, it is possible that when you instantiated the class with `gensim.models.Word2Vec()`, that the parameter `documents` is not actually necessary

try this instead:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(
    size=150,
    window=10,
    min_count=2,
    workers=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that model doesn't take the keyword parameter `documents` on initialization. I think you could try either of these in replacement of your `documents=` statement:

```
corpus_file = 'userDataFile.txt'
```

or

```
sentences = # your iterable of sentences here
```

Depending on the format of what you're working with