# How can I still use the 'wv' attribute of this (probably deprecated?) package/module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, gensim, word2vec

I am new to the Gensim package, and I am trying to get a little familiar with it. I am now trying to import an existing, trained model. I am following exactly the example from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1VsHYcNXDI&t=330s) (this section starts at 5:30). When I run the code from that video I get an error:

Code:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, KeyedVectors
import pandas as pd
import nltk

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True, limit=100000)

model.wv.most_similar('man')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:....", line 7, in <module>
    model.wv.most_similar('man')
AttributeError: 'KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'wv'
```

In a previous example I also ran into a similar problem when training an own model (namely with the name of the `size` parameter, which turned out to be changed to `vector_size`, because the package is deprecated I read). That probably only happened quite recently, because in the comments of the YouTube video I do not read about such problems yet. And that fix about that `size` parameter that was renamed was also from [a post here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195906/getting-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-document-this-error-in/67080756#67080756) that is only 2 weeks old.

Does anyone know how I can still use this `wv` attribute, so that I can just continue with the example from the video?

Comment: I am not familiar with this library, but the [first result](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) using Google provides an answer. `wv` is not an attribute of `KeyedVectors` but of `Word2Vec`. You can probably use `most_similar` on your `model` variable.

Answer (score 2):

The comment from user ~BoobyTrap is correct. Your `KeyedVectors` instance already supports `.most_similar()`. There is no need to request its `.wv` property. You should just do:

```py
model.wv.most_similar('man')
```

As you can see in the video, when it was prepared, there was already a deprecation warning, that `.wv` would be going away. (So, the creator of that video could have left it out then - it wasn't necessary, it was already generating a warning message that it would break soon, and using it indicates an incomplete understanding of the roles of the various object types.)

The only objects that now have `.wv` property are those which include a consituent `KeyedVectors`, like a full `Word2Vec` model. That is, when you have an object with a lot of extra state, but that has a set-of-word-vectors as one of its important parts, they are likely to be found in that object's `.wv` property.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same, and super THANKS! to gojomo's detailed explanation, got to sort out.
So basically just take away the "wv".

<Example 1: to view the word embedding for 'king'>

FROM;

```
model_0123.wv['king']
```

To;

```
model_0123['king']
```

<Example 2: to get 20 of similar words for 'king'>

FROM;

```
model_0123.wv.most_similar(positive=['king'], topn=20)
```

To;

```
model_0123.most_similar(positive=['king'], topn=20)
```